# Huh? findViewById() can't be called inside onReceive()?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, findviewbyid

In one of my classes, I attempt to access a View (in my main layout) in response to a broadcast received:

```
  protected BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
      String action = intent.getAction();
      if ( action.equals("com.mydomain.myapp.INTERESTING_EVENT_OCCURRED") ) {
        ((Activity) ctx).setContentView(R.layout.main);
        LinearLayout linLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lin_layout);
        if (linLayout != null) {
          Log.i(TAG_OK, "OK to proceed with accessing views inside layout");
        }
        else
          Log.e(TAG_FAIL, "What's wrong with calling findViewById inside onReceive()?");
      }
    }       
  };
```

The problem is that findViewById() always returns null and as result I always get the TAG_FAIL error message.

The **same exact** `findViewById(R.id.lin_layout)` call inside activity's [onCreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29) returns the desired result, so I know it's *not* a typo or some other error in the code quoted above.

Why is this happening?

Is there a restriction on on calling [findViewById()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById%28int%29) inside a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)?

or some other reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BroadcastReceiver is its own class and does not inherit from android.app.Activity, yes?  So by that logic, you can't expect it to include Activity's methods.

Pass the context to your BroadcastReceiver, or more directly, pass a reference to the view that you want to manipulate.

```
// package protected access
LinearLayout linLayout;

onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    linLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lin_layout);
}

protected BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent)
    {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if ( action.equals("com.mydomain.myapp.INTERESTING_EVENT_OCCURRED"))
        {
            if (linLayout != null)
            {
                Log.i(TAG_OK, "OK to proceed with accessing views inside layout");
            }
            else
                Log.e(TAG_FAIL, "What's wrong with calling findViewById inside onReceive()?");
            }
        }       
    };
```

Comment: On top of that, I'm pretty sure `findViewById` is simply a convenience method for: `YourActivity.this.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.your_id);`.  You're getting confused because you've probably written your broadcast receiver as an inner class of your Activity which is why you have access to your activitie's methods.  If your Receiver gets an intent when the activitie's views cease to exist, getRootView() would return null.  I'm guessing this is the root of your problem.

Comment: @DavidCowden Huh? the cast receiver here is **not** an inner class of my Activity. Note that onReceive() itself passes `Context`. I am just casting it to Activity. Am I not allowed to cast Context to Activity?

Comment: @MarsAtomic What do you mean by "Pass the context to your BroadcastReceiver"? Context is already being passed to onReceive(). Thanks to both of you.

Comment: By defining onReceive(), which is a member method of your BroadcastReceiver, you're clearly defining an inner class.  Then you're trying to use methods that belong to Activity inside of that.  Compare what you've written to simply protected BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver();  Also, true, you are passing the context, but you're not using it properly.  **See edited answer**

Comment: @both of you: It's actually an anonymous inner class but whatever.  @MarsAtomic I suggest a small correction to your code.  You have two options:  1 try to cast the received context to an instance of the activity that has the linlayout member or 2 simply check if linlayout is null and procede from there.  You can't do `ctx.linlayout` as you've written because no context has a linlayout member.  You have to cast it first or take advantage of the pseudo closures you get when using inner classes in Java.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that ctx.linLayout would not work.  That's what happens when you spew code into a simple editor rather than an IDE.  Example code corrected, compiles in Eclipse.  It's not easy trying to debug other people's code to take your own mind off of the design issue you can't resolve while conquering the world in Civ5 and trying to catch up on Mad Men all at the same time.